# Random numbers, C++11 vs Boost

Tags: performance, boost, c++11, random

I want to generate pseudo-random numbers in C++, and the two likely options are the  feature of C++11 and the Boost counterpart. They are used in essentially the same way, but the native one in my tests is roughly 4 times slower.

Is that due to design choices in the library, or am I missing some way of disabling debug code somewhere?

**Update:** Code is here, https://github.com/vbeffara/Simulations/blob/master/tests/test_prng.cpp and looks like this:

```
cerr << "boost::bernoulli_distribution ...      \ttime = ";
s=0; t=time();
boost::bernoulli_distribution<> dist(.5);
boost::mt19937 boostengine;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) s += dist(boostengine);
cerr << time()-t << ",  \tsum = " << s << endl;

cerr << "C++11 style ...                        \ttime = ";
s=0; t=time();
std::bernoulli_distribution dist2(.5);
std::mt19937_64 engine;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) s += dist2(engine);
cerr << time()-t << ",  \tsum = " << s << endl;
```

(Using `std::mt19937` instead of `std::mt19937_64` makes it even slower on my system.)

Comment: Yep, that is probably a good idea. Updated, thanks.

Comment: be careful, mt19937 and mt19937_64 are different RNGs.

Comment: Mersenne twister is pretty straightforward, I'm not sure there's room for it to be 4x slower. You should try benchmarking just the distribution.

Comment: @CoryNelson Fair enough - but both perform at about the same speed in my test

Comment: @CoryNelson I don't so much care about the engine as about the distribution. Each of the two versions shown is the fastest I could find for generating Bernoulli variable in either framework. Tossing Bernoulli coins should be even more straightforward than running a Mersenne Twister ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[That’s](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d288a259583d7cb2) pretty scary.

Let’s have a look:

boost::bernoulli_distribution<>

```
if(_p == RealType(0))
    return false;
else
    return RealType(eng()-(eng.min)()) <= _p * RealType((eng.max)()-(eng.min)());
```

std::bernoulli_distribution

```
__detail::_Adaptor<_UniformRandomNumberGenerator, double> __aurng(__urng);
if ((__aurng() - __aurng.min()) < __p.p() * (__aurng.max() - __aurng.min()))
    return true;
return false;
```

Both versions invoke the engine and check if the output lies in a portion of the range of values proportional to the given probability.

The big difference is, that the gcc version calls the functions of a helper class `_Adaptor`.

This class’ `min` and `max` functions return `0` and `1` respectively and `operator()` then calls `std::generate_canonical` with the given URNG to obtain a value between `0` and `1`.

`std::generate_canonical` is a 20 line function with a loop – which will never iteratate more than once in this case, but it adds complexity.

Apart from that, boost uses the `param_type` only in the constructor of the distribution, but then saves `_p` as a `double` member, whereas gcc has a `param_type` member and has to “get” the value of it.

This all comes together and the compiler [fails in optimizing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba96355d060c06a7). 
Clang [chokes even more](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94a5c17d657dfd45) on it.

If you [hammer hard enough](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f2e38c1d4454e98) you can even get `std::mt19937` and `boost::mt19937` en par for gcc.

It would be nice to test libc++ too, maybe i’ll add that later.

---

tested versions: boost 1.55.0, libstdc++ headers of gcc 4.8.2
line numbers on request^^

Comment: Ouch! I wanted to remove a boost dependency from my code but I guess it is not such a good idea. Unless I do my own implementation of bernoulli_distribution on top of std::mt19937 ... In cases like that it is hard (for me) to really see the point of fully parameterized template code where I would believe everybody is using the defaults, or a dedicated library.

The more I learn the more respect I have for all the work put into boost.

Comment: Okay, I did this:
    `class local_bernoulli_distribution {
    public:
        explicit local_bernoulli_distribution (double p = 0.5)
            : thr(p * unsigned(-1)) {}
        bool operator() (std::mt19937 & e) { return e() < thr; }
    private:
        const unsigned thr;
    };`
Slightly better than the standard (1.5s against 2.0s) but not to the level of boost (.5s). Boost it is then!

Comment: I don’t really get what you mean with »fully parameterized template code«.  
The difference here is, that the distributions of libstdc++ are mere a wrapper around `_Adaptor`, whereas boost has a direct implementation. 
You can superseed the speed of boost if you use  
`template <typename Engine> inline bool operator() (Engine & e) `.  
But nonetheless you’re better off using boost.

Comment: Note: `std::generate_canonical` uses as many generator cycles as necessary to produce the target type. The example uses `bernoulli_distribution` which uses `double` (53-bit mantissa), thus requiring 7 generator cycles with an 8-bit generator (2 cycles with 32-bit generators). Of course the extra precision is wasted here, but technically the C++ equivalent of uniform01 is more precise.