# Boost rng vs OpenCV rng vs c++11 std::random?

Tags: c++, opencv, boost

It is just a simple question, I need some opinions.

I am using both `boost` and `OpenCV`, and I want to generate a random number. Which is better to use: the `boost::random::uniform_int_distribution` (boost random integer generator) or `cv::RNG`?

I have written this:

```
// OpenCV RNG:
cv::RNG rngCV(cv::getTickCount());
int randInt = rngCV.uniform(0, 100); // generates integer number in [0, 100)
std::cout << "cv::RNG: " << randInt << std::endl;

// Boost RNG:
boost::random::mt19937 gen(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0)));
boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> rngBoost(0, 99);
int randInt2 = rngBoost(gen);
std::cout << "boost::random: " << randInt2 << std::endl;

// c++11 random
std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine el(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution< int > unif_distr(0, 99);
int randInt3 = unif_distr(el);
std::cout << "std::random: " << randInt3 << std::endl;
```

Which one do you suggest me to do? Both are working well.

Comment: What do you have to do? Any particular need?

Comment: I want to generate particular IDs

Comment: If you're looking to generate unique Ids, you might want to check out Boost.Uuid: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/uuid/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C++11, there is a random generator engine that is in the standard library.
Nothing comparable with the old rand() function from C.
There are a bunch of random distributions, you can specify the interval ...

Comment: Nice, I have edited the question: added c++11 random, so Which one?

Comment: Well as Brandon Kohn pointed out, boost is more portable/standard than opencv. And obviously, the standard library is even more ... standard. So I will go for the default_random_engine. And I think they are all three equivalent in term of speed and quality.

Comment: Are you sure about Boost and C++11 random libs being equivalent? [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998470/random-numbers-c11-vs-boost). I can reproduce, even after fixing min and max, or replacing with a real RNG (PCG).

Answer (score 2):

The boost interface is much more like what got into the standard. So if you plan to go that route at some point, it might be easier to change if you're using boost.